# Parsing Logs Using Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse the Cisco ASA logs I am getting but i want specific logs to be parsed, saved and showed on Kibana. I've written a code but its still showing a lot of logs that I do not want. I am not sure why its not parsing the code properly, I have a feeling its the variable I am trying to match.

I need it to only show me any log that is labelled ASA severity 1-4 and log ASA-6-106100

`

```
filter {
    if [type] == "syslog" {
        if [%{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}] =~ \b(\w*ASA-[1-4]\w*)\b {
            grok {
                match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
                add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
                add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
            }
            date {
                match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
            }
        }
        else if [%{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}] =~ \b(\w*106100\w*)\b {
            grok {
                match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
                add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
                add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
            }
            date {
                match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
            }
        }
        else {
            break_on_match
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: What's the problem that you're facing - that the existing groks you have don't work, or that you're indexes messages that don't match those patterns?

Comment: actually i found out that im facing two problems now. the first being that my logstash configuration doesnt start working immediately but it takes sometime and sometimes it doesnt go through and it keeps using the old configuration

Comment: Neither of those are typical with logstash.  Might you have an old copy of logstash running?